# How to resolve android manifest not found in at the run time in android studio at the first time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

today i installed android studio and faced many problem. I ran the sample hello world program and i'm getting error for manifest file not found.How can i solve this problem ?

> Error:Android Source Generator: [MyApplication] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Comment: when i run the project they can popup edit configure view, there is showing in the edit configure page like showing error like this _android manifest file missing or has incorrect root tag_ .how can i solve this problem

Comment: Where is your AndroidManifest.xml file located? Can you post a photo of your project directory view?

Comment: After restart the computer android studio working normally. Thank you!